# Cannot find BLE devices using web bluetooth on Android Phone from a web app

Tags: android, google-chrome, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I have created a web application that is used to connect to the nearby BLE devices using web Bluetooth API on google chrome to read and write data. the web application is hosted on heroku and it is running as expected when accessed on PC (chrome version: 104.0.5112.102), i.e., the Bluetooth scanning and discovery is working perfectly. But when I try to access the web app using my android phone (OnePlus 7T with chrome version 105.0.5195.79), the pop window for BLE scanning is showing, but it does not discover any nearby BLE devices. Can someone help me out??

Comment: please share the link of the webapp so that others can also try and check what might be the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot share the web app since it is a part of my Thesis work

Comment: you can try with turning on the location service (GPS). also check by setting the accuracy to high.

Comment: Have tried it, but the same result. The website is scanning for BLE devices, but detecting it. I had enabled the experimental flags for Web Platform in chrome too. What I really don't understand is why it is not detecting the device in android phone but works perfectly on my PC !!

Comment: you try with some ready samples or demos for testing. may be it is your phone issue or you are missing some steps.

Comment: hey, were you able to solve the issue?
I'm having the same issue where it connects on chrome PC but not on chrome Android or chrome iOS.

Comment: I also have my own web app that used to connect to my MI Scale via BLE in javascript and show the current weight ... It no longer returns this device (in fact, getDevices stopped working altogether and I had to enable the experimental web features flag for some reason just to get the .getDevices() function present, yet this used to work a week ago)...
Now, .getDevices() returns an empty list no matter what I try so I can't see my scale.
I can Pair with it it and download the history, but watching doesn't work because there are no devices listed to be watched.

Answer (score 0):

Are you scanning for beacons? iBeacon and Eddystone are filtered on Android 12+ because Chrome's manifest declares the `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` permission with `neverForLocation`.

> If your app doesn't use Bluetooth scan results to derive physical location, you can make a strong assertion that your app never uses the Bluetooth permissions to derive physical location. To do so, complete the following steps:
>
> 1. Add the `android:usesPermissionFlags` attribute to your `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` permission declaration, and set this attribute's value to `neverForLocation`.
>
> **Note:** If you include `neverForLocation` in your `android:usesPermissionFlags`, some BLE beacons are filtered from the scan results.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#assert-never-for-location

The relevant Chrome issue is https://crbug.com/1324831

Comment: Can I do something about chrome android. I'm using webBluetoothAPI to connect to custom RFID reader. Same problem it works on desktop but not on android.